# Is it best-practice to commit the `vendor` directory?

Tags: go

I am using `dep` to handle my Go dependencies. Is it best practice to also commit the `vendor` directory into version control? Or is best practice to always execute `dep ensure` after checking out a repository?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `dep` tool's FAQ [answers](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#should-i-commit-my-vendor-directory) this:

> **Should I commit my vendor directory?**
>
> It's up to you:
>
> Pros
>
> - It's the only way to get truly reproducible builds, as it guards
>   against upstream renames, deletes and commit history overwrites.
> - You don't need an extra `dep ensure` step to sync `vendor/` with
>   `Gopkg.lock` after most operations, such as go get, cloning, getting
>   latest, merging, etc.
>
> Cons
>
> - Your repo will be bigger, potentially a lot bigger, though [prune](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md#prune) can help minimize this problem.
> - PR diffs will include changes for files under `vendor/` when `Gopkg.lock` is modified, however files in `vendor/` are [hidden by default](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/v5.2.0/lib/linguist/generated.rb#L328) on GitHub.

Comment: Another pro is that when you use CI there is no need to download dependencies every time you run your pipeline.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate for Go 1.11+ with modules enabled.

Comment: I prefer to commit the vendor folder.
I was experiencing some of the repo is gone, probably because some company bought it.

Comment: In my opinion this answer is still accurate , however replace `dep ensure` with `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor`.  Replace `Gopkg.lock` with `go.sum`.

I check in vendor because I weigh the first pro here quite heavily.  I cant afford the lose dependencies and repositories can be change to private, be renamed or moved, or be deleted entirely.

Comment: You have also very cluttered merge requests, searching git history diff standard way is slow and flooded with clutter, backing up project you normally need only your code, not 20 other dependencies where often your code makes only 10% of entire filesize at best

Answer (score 8):

imagine what would happen to your project if a dependency was taken offline by the author. Until Go has a central server to hold all packages which are unable to be deleted a lot of people will always see the need to commit the vendor folder

Comment: While I understand the idea, I think that's not the way. You don't put, let's say, `gtest` library together with your C++ project, you don't put `requests` library together with your Python project, you don't put your JS and PHP `vendor`/`node` folder together with your web projects. You don't put **any** library together with your project in any language. Why on Earth Golang should be different?

Comment: @TheGodfather Because it very easily can.

Comment: That server now exists: https://proxy.golang.org/

Comment: @the-godfather with age comes wisdom, and since I wrote that answer I have come to agree with you

Comment: This argument can be made for just about any of those languages. Maven, Composer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t commit for well available sources. Because on this case many commit messages are bloated with changes in vendors. When I want update then I do it and then commit updated `Gopkg.*`.