# Should I commit vendor directory with go mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am using go modules on go1.12 to handle my Go dependencies. Is it best practice to also commit the `vendor/` directory into version control?

This is somewhat related to [Is it best-practice to commit the `vendor` directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47346607) which asks this question in the case of using `dep`. With `dep`, commiting `vendor/` is the only way to get truly reproducible builds. What about for go modules?

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? [Is it best-practise to commit \`vendor\` directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346607/is-it-best-practise-to-commit-vendor-directory)

Comment: @Tom: That answer is not relevant for go modules.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd like to give some arguments **in favour** of committing `vendor`, `go.mod` and `go.sum`.

I agree with the accepted answer's arguments that it's technically unnecessary and bloats the repo.

But here is a list of pro-arguments:

- Building the project doesn't depend on some code being available on Github/Gitlab/... or the Go proxy servers. Open source projects may disappear because of censorship, authors incentives, licensing changes or some other reasons I can't currently think of, which [did happen on npm, the JavaScript package manager, and broke many projects](https://www.theverge.com/2016/3/24/11300840/how-an-irate-developer-briefly-broke-javascript). **Not in your repo, not your code.**
- We may have used internal or 3rd party Go modules (private) which may also disappear or become inaccessible, but if they are committed in vendor, they are part of our project. **Nothing breaks unexpectedly.**
- Private Go modules may not follow semantic versioning, which means the Go tools will rely on the latest commit hash when fetching them on-the-fly. Repo history may be rewritten (e.g. rebase) and you, a colleague or your CI job may end up with different code for the dependencies they use.
- CI/CD jobs which perform compilation and build steps will not waste time and network to download the dependencies every time the CI job is executed. All needed dependencies are local and present (`go build -mod vendor`)
- Setting up CI/CD jobs authentication for downloading private Go modules is not necessary (simpler).
- Go dependencies almost always are text files (source code) and it's very cheap to store them in the repo. Not the case for every other language.
- Committing vendor may sometimes improve the code review process. Typically we always commit dependency changes in a separate commit, so they can be easily viewed if you're curious.

Here's an interesting observation related to bloating the repo. If someone makes a code review and a team member has included a new dependency with 300 files (or updated one with 300 files changed), it may be interesting to look inside and eventually start a discussion about alternatives/quality if needed. This may lead to actually decrease your binary size and overall complexity.

If there is just a single new line in `go.mod` in a new Merge Request, chances are we won't even think about it.

*When committing vendor is wrong?*

`vendor` **should never** be committed when the project is a Go library (imagine you make the new gorilla/mux). Only for projects that produce executable binaries.

Comment: actually this is a correct answer, I even don't see any reasons why you need a vendor folder if you not going to commit it in a first place, lol

Comment: This is especially true if you're working at a company on "professional" code. Effectively managing your software supply chain, and keeping old projects working is super important, and you'll be thankful you had some mirroring setup in place. It might not matter initially, but if you need to rebuild a project that's decades old, you'll be thankful you vendored. If you don't have a fancy local proxy within your in your company, checking in `vendor` is a an easy solution to this issue.

Comment: Yes, it also means you can run the program without external network access.

Comment: god yes! number one goal of software is to be true and correct, not hand wavy vague.

Answer (score 13):

Unless you need to modify the vendored packages, you shouldn't. Go modules already gives you reproducible builds as the `go.mod` file records the exact versions and commit hashes of your dependencies, which the `go` tool will respect and follow.

The `vendor` directory can be recreated by running the `go mod vendor` command, and it's even ignored by default by `go build` unless you ask it to use it with the `-mod=vendor` flag.

Read more details:

[Go wiki: How do I use vendoring with modules? Is vendoring going away?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away)

[Command go: Modules and vendoring](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules_and_vendoring)

[Command go: Make vendored copies of dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Make_vendored_copy_of_dependencies)

Comment: There are a few other cases when vendoring modules might make sense that might be worth mentioning: If the modules are imported from a private repo that is impractical or impossible to access from your CI/build scripts, or if you fear it may disappear due to an unstable server or something, or if you're using [GopherJS, which doesn't support modules yet](https://jhall.io/posts/gopherjs-with-modules/) :)

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, thanks. Although published modules won't disappear, even if the original repository goes private or extinct, the official module mirror will continue to serve them.

Comment: If you're not going to commit the vendored modules to the repo, what would be the point of vendoring?

Comment: does "go mod vendor" require access to the internet? this might be an issue in CI / build scripts like what @Flimzy mentioned

Comment: IMO this answer is not good, maybe even harmful for new Go developers. What happens when a dependency projects is removed from github? Why the kubernetes project (and many many more) put and commit their vendor folder?

Comment: @luben When a project is removed from github, everything will continue to work because the Go proxy servers have copies of public modules.

Comment: @icza Until when? What guarantee is provided by the Go proxy public services that they will (and for how long) continue to provide a Go module when it's project is deleted from github? What if the dependency is removed because of some censorship from both github and the Go proxy service? The point is that all these assumptions and expectations are not under our control, while packages committed in the vendor are local and are totally under our control in our projects.

Comment: The comment in the original post about `go mod vendor` being ignored by default is not valid now. Quoting from [current go modules reference](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring):

_"If the vendor directory is present in the main module’s root directory, it will be used automatically if the go version in the main module’s go.mod file is 1.14 or higher. To explicitly enable vendoring, invoke the go command with the flag -mod=vendor. To disable vendoring, use the flag -mod=readonly or -mod=mod."_